# How to get the previous value of another field when I have specific data?

Tags: t-sql

I have a Message table with these columns:

`````````````````````````````````````
UNIT    State     LogID    MessageID
````````````````````````````````````
Unit1   Status1   1        1
Unit8   Status2   5        1
Unit3   *         3        1
Unit5   Status3   6        1
Unit2   Status2   11       5
Unit6   *         2        5
Unit4   Status4   8        5
Unit11  *         9        5
`````````````````````````````````````

---

I want to get  the previous value of Unit field when my state of messages is *
I need this result at last:

``````````````````````````````````
UNIT    State   LogID   MessageID
`````````````````````````````````
Unit8   *       3       1
Unit2   *       2       5
Unit4   *       9       5
``````````````````````````````````

Comment: I don't have a complete answer but I think you're going to need to use [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

Comment: Not possible with what you have shown here. You need a column that defines the order of rows.

Comment: @Mikael is right, remember a table is a heap and don't have a intrinsic ordering, you must define one using ORDER BY clause. For what you give us it sounds as you are missing a ordering column here